# How to share a file (data) across multiple docker containers in azure

Tags: azure, nginx

I want to run several docker containers in different regions (asia, eu, us) which host a nginx server.

However, they should all have the same configuration because I need to updated hostnames at runtime dynamically (one domain for every new tenant).
So I guess it would be the easiest way to just share one config file among all containers and reload them...

So how can I share data/files among n containers on azure?

Comment: thanks for offering the bounty!  Now that the question is no longer featured, please make sure to accept an answer or explicitly award the bounty; otherwise, at least half of the value will be lost forever.

Answer (score 1):

In general, unless you want to use proprietary solutions specific to the platform at hand, the best way to synchronise files between multiple systems is with the help of [***`rsync`***](http://ports.su/net/rsync).

For example, in DNS, there exists a specialised protocol for transferring domain zones directly within the DNS software, called `AXFR`; one of the authors of a newer DNS implementation suggests that this *AXFR* protocol is crap, and *rsync over ssh* works much better — http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/tcp.html — and the ssh part is a nice thing about rsync, in that it can work over plain old ssh protocol as far as interconnection between the hosts goes, not requiring any special firewall considerations.

Comment: yah, that sounds like a feasible approach. Nevertheless I would need to take care of all server who should get an update. With a "mounted shared" volume it would be much easier to maintain, right?

Comment: @dc10 This can all be done automatically through a [cron](http://mdoc.su/o/cron.8) job; and, as others have mentioned, nowadays in 2017 you can also use [`git`](http://ports.su/devel/git) in place of `rsync` (the linked DJBDNS article was written in 2002, but the approach aged very well, IMHO).  There are pros and cons of every solution; the main benefit of the crontab/rsync/git route is that you're not needlessly trying yourself to proprietary solutions when the standard UNIX way does the job very well as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [Azure file share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-mounting-azure-files-volume).